# 64-bit Windows 7 fopen prn

Tags: windows-7, printing

I am using my antique Borland Builder 5 with Windows 7 64-bit.

1. fptr=fopen("\prn","wb") fails. "prn", "prn:" also fail.
2. fptr=fopen("HP8 lj4","wb") succeeds. But doesn't print anything. The "HP8 lj4" is the name of a printer; in control panel, or via "net view hp8gig".
3. The console command { print /D:"HP8 lj4" shopping.ln } says "shopping.ln is currently being printed" -- but doesn't print anything either.
4. Of course I print things on that printer all the time. My beautiful ASCII TSE editor can do it.

Anybody know how to print from a console program in Windows 7?

//Monday, September 12, 2011 5:29 pm. Later I realized my "HP8 lj4" was printing to a file with that name. And I tried to comment here, but apparently failed....

Comment: There is a commercial product to print from dos, printfil. Perhaps there are alternatives OR use DoxBox.

Answer (score 1):

Tue 9/13/2011 4:05 pm. The way to print from a console "prn"-oriented program in Windows 7 et al is "net use lpt1: \hp8gig\UrPrinter /PERSISTENT:YES". "UrPrinter" must be "shared". And that's all it takes; my wretched little console program prints fine now. One reason I got confused, aside from natural talent, was that the desired printer was *local*. It was attached to the computer -- but via USB. After doing this, a command-line like "copy file /b prn" prints.

I knew this before apparently -- I found it in a "printnet.bat" file I wrote, to access a network printer from *another* computer -- but obviously I forgot.

So the code from the web site I mentioned before was broken -- a few typos -- and even when it worked, didn't. Which is to say, I still don't know how to *programmatically* do the "net use" thing.

Answer (score 0):

Mon 9/12/2011 5:49 pm. OK the general problem is how to redirect the revered &
antique "PRN" device on a windows 7 machine to something useful. I don't know
how to do that. A fellow at
http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/win32/NetworkPrint.htm has some code which looks
like it might make PRN print again, but his plan also suggested trying the
network name of my desired printer in my silly program -- and that works.
I.e., I stuck in code like

```
  if (stricmp(name,"prn")==0) {
    name =
#if W7
      "\\\\hp8gig\\HP8 lj4"
#endif
  }
```

I can make something more sophisticated with an environment variable, or
perhaps I'll figure-out the fellow's PRN thing....