# Printing through printer c++

Tags: c++

I am Making A Program To Book ticket and i want to print the ticket.I am willing to use text files but after days of searching i didn't get an useful code which works

In my book The following code is given

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<process.h>

int main()
{
    char filename[13];

    cout<<"enter The Filename";
    cin.getline(filename,12);

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(filename);

    if(!fin)
    {
        cerr<<"file cannot Be Opened";
        exit(-1);
    }    

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("PRN");

    char ch;

    while(fin.get(ch)!=0)
        fout.put(ch);

    fout.close();
    fin.close(); 

    return 0;   
}
```

the above code executes but no effect is observed

Note I am using borland 5.02 and am not willing to jump into WinAPI or MFC

Comment: if the data is small, u should fclose your file so the data will be flushed. U must always fclose your file, be in that specific example it can be the problem.

Comment: closed the file but no effects are observed

Comment: BTW, you should consider using the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler `g++`, it is free software, available on many platforms (notably Linux) and targets, and (in its latest release 4.9.1 in august 2014) much better (optimizing well, and quite conform to latest C++11 standard). Your code is obsolete these days!

Comment: I have to use borland 5.02. it is an standard used at my school and the board

Comment: add a cout << ch << endl; to check if the ch is getting the data

Comment: Tried. ch is getting the data but no effect is observed ie, it is not being printed through the printer

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7407902/3723423

Comment: Borland C++ 5.02 still tries to follow the C++98 standard. If you plan to use C++ beyond your school you probably want to learn and follow that too. C++98 is still obsolete by some 7 years but it's better than the pre-standard fossilized crap that clueless educators are shoving down their students' throats.

Answer (score 0):

In 2004, I have encountered a lof of problem to print document from C++ program. I have tried to used Windows MFC API but this don't work well. So I have found another solution that continues to work in 2018 using Visual Studio 2017 !

```
 XString sCmd;
 XString sDevice = "\\\\localhost\\DefaultPrinter";

 sCmd.Clear() << "net use LPT1: " << sDevice;
 iRetCode = system(sCmd);

 sCmd.Clear() << "print /D:LPT1 " << sFile;
 iRetCode = system(sCmd);

 sCmd = "net use LPT1: /delete";
 iRetCode = system(sCmd);
```

The class XString is a clone of MFC CString enhanced so that code work on Windows and BS2000 (Siemens Operating System = Betrieb System in german).

This code work only if you define a shared printed named "DefaultPrinter" on each PC where C++ EXE must run.

Without using XString, and in simplifying some lines, the code can be:

```
std::string sDevice = "\\\\localhost\\DefaultPrinter";

system(string("net use LPT1: ") + sDevice);
system(string("print /D:LPT1 ") + sFileToPrint;
system("net use LPT1: /delete");
```